# What is the difference between radar cross section and intensity/amplitude?

Tags: signal-processing, radar

I've been tasked with simulating a radar system, and I think I understand the problem, except I'm supposed to be providing the outputs in both radar cross section and amplitude.

What's the difference? Is there some good literature on the subject?

I thought this was essentially a camera that operates in the radio band: illuminate the scene, evaluate returns. Aperture width in wavelengths determines how wide or narrow the illuminating beam is... should be pretty straightforward for at least a first pass approximation, but I've got test data from the actual device giving cross section and amplitude and the two don't seem to correlate at all, so I can't figure out what the difference is between the two.

How could a radar register a large cross-sectional area with a low amplitude return or vice versa? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Radar cross-section (RCS) is a property of the target independent of the measurement.

Quoting from the Wikipedia article for [Radar cross-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Radar_cross-section&oldid=1082600471):

> Informally, the RCS of an object is the cross-sectional area of a
> perfectly reflecting sphere that would produce the same strength
> reflection as would the object in question. (Bigger sizes of this
> imaginary sphere would produce stronger reflections.) Thus, RCS is an
> abstraction: the radar cross-sectional area of an object does not
> necessarily bear a direct relationship with the physical
> cross-sectional area of that object but depends upon other factors.
>
> Somewhat less informally, the RCS of a radar target is an effective
> area that intercepts the transmitted radar power and then scatters
> that power isotropically back to the radar receiver.
>
> More precisely,
> the RCS of a radar target is the hypothetical area required to
> intercept the transmitted power density at the target such that if the
> total intercepted power were re-radiated isotropically, the power
> density actually observed at the receiver is produced.

This is typically expressed in what is known as the [radar range equation](https://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/The%20Radar%20Range%20Equation.en.html) which relates the sensor (the radar) and target properties.  The following is one (of may equivalent) ways of representing the relationship:

$$P_R = \frac{P_T G_T G_R}{\left(4\pi\right)^2 R^4}\sigma$$

where $P_R$ is the received power, $P_T$ is the transmitted power, $G_T$ is the transmit [antenna gain](https://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/gain.php), $G_R$ is the receive antenna gain, $R$ is the range from the sensor to the target, and $\sigma$ is the radar cross-section.

All of these terms are properties of the sensor or environment except the RCS which is properly of the target.

Comment: I understand that radar cross-section is a property of the target, but that target must be sensed, right? And so my question isn't really, "What is a radar cross-section," but rather, "How does a sensor determine the radar cross-section of a target?" I have actual data off actual automotive radar devices that report return amplitude and target cross-section and there's no relationship I can discern between the two - different amplitude readings can result in the same area. I can only assume that there must be some other signal processing technique at play but I can't find anything about it.